# Project Euler # 255

Tags: python

[Project euler problem #255](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=255) is quite mathematical. I figured out how it is done for given example. Since I am a newbie in Python, I am not sure how to handle long range values. Below is the solution I have. But how does it work for 10^13 and 10^14?

```
def ceil(a, b):
 return (a + b - 1) / b;

def func(a, b):
 return (b + ceil(a, b)) / 2;

def calculate(a):
 ctr = 1;
 y = 200;
 while 1:
  z = func(a, y);
  if z == y:
   return ctr;
  y = z;
  ctr += 1;

result = sum(map(calculate, xrange(10000, 100000))) / 9e4;
print "%.10f" % result;
```

This gives 3.2102888889.

Comment: please, use 4-spaced indents...

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `map`. It generates a big list in memory.

Don't use `xrange`.  It is limited to short integers.

Use generators instead.

```
# No changes on `ceil()`, `func()` and `calculate()`

def generate_sequence(start, stop):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += 1

result = sum(calculate(n) for n in generate_sequence(10**13, 10**14))
print "%.10f" % result;
```

That will run. But it will take a long time to sum `10**14 - 10**13 = 90,000,000,000,000` results. Maybe there's something else you can do to optimize *(hint, hint)*

Comment: You can always use imap instead of map: "from itertools import imap"

Answer (score 1):

Even a very fast calculation for each number will take too long. To satisfy the 1 minute rule you'd need to solve/add 1.5 Trillion numbers per second.

I think there must be a way to compute the result more directly.

Answer (score 0):

90,000,000,000,000 is a lot of numbers to check, I tried checking every millionth number and thought the average would be close enough, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[3.6.3 XRange Type](http://python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-xrange.html) :

> "3.6.3 XRange Type
>
> The xrange type is an immutable
>   sequence which is commonly used for
>   looping. The advantage of the xrange
>   type is that an xrange object will
>   always take the same amount of memory,
>   no matter the size of the range it
>   represents. There are no consistent
>   performance advantages.
>
> XRange objects have very little
>   behavior: they only support indexing,
>   iteration, and the len() function."

maybe ... optimize your floor and ceiling functions? :P

Comment: as a sidenote: Can you comment on [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306253/a-moan-about-koans) about your reasons for adding tags to old questions?